# How to get occurrence count of specific field value in elasticsearch from 650 M data

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have indexed Twitter data in ES. There are **110 M Twitter unique users profiles** and there **650 M Tweets**. Both are in seperate index (index: twitter-profiles, type: profiles), for tweets (index: twitter-tweets, type: tweets).

There is **user_id_str** of profile is attached with every tweet.

I am running into a problem to get **occurrence count of specific user**. I used **Facet/terms and Aggregation/Terms** but both give me exception **PartialShardFailureException** because there are lot of data to make calculation.
I used following query

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "userCount" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "user_id_str" }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I give another Try.

I used second method **Scan**. Here I get ids of profiles from profiles type then search it in tweet type. it give me results but a single result came after **2seconds** OOps. There are 110 M users mean I have to wait for days.

Please give me any reasonable solution for this situation.

Comment: What is the mapping? Did you use non_analyzed on the mentioned field? How many shards do you use? How many nodes?

Comment: Yes the field I am looking for is not_analyzed, There are 6 shards and three nodes running on Amazon's Ec2 servers

Comment: The scan is used to go through all the data with sorting or scoring. If you want to aggregate over all the users (110 M), there can be a memory problem. More shards and more nodes with more memory could be an option. Maybe try with a more limited dataset and see the results than.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [Cardinality](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) aggregation in combination with [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html)